# Is there any reason to ".destroy()" a readable stream in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

If I create a readable stream in a block in Node.js like this:

```
const fs = require("fs");
{
  const stream = fs.createReadStream("file.txt");
  ....
 }
```

Is there then any reason to do `stream.destroy()` at the end of the block where `stream` is defined? Or, can I safely assume that Javascript/Node.js does that for me?